# Multiply sum columns in a pivot query with another column

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

I have three tables, SUsers, Questions, and Votes.

-SUsers- have columns:
SID,SHName,EmailAdd,Password,DoneVoting,AccessLevel, and NumberOfShares

-Questions- have columns: QID, and Questions.

-Votes- have columns: VID, SID, QID, VoteDate, and Answer.

The questions are answerable by "In Order", "Against", and "Abstain."

For example, I have user 1 who have NumberOfShares of 100. The user's one vote will be multiplied by 100.

Currenty, I have this working stored procedure that only gets one vote per user. I'm having a difficulty of multiplying it with the NumberOfShares.

Here's my stored proc.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_VotingTally2]
 @dateFrom NVARCHAR(MAX),
 @dateTo NVARCHAR(MAX)

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @columns = COALESCE(@columns + ',','') + QUOTENAME([QID])
FROM    (SELECT [QID] FROM [PressRelease].[dbo].[Questions]) st
ORDER BY st.[QID]

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)  
SET @sql = 
    'SELECT * FROM (
         SELECT b.[QID],[Answer],[Answer] as Answers FROM [PressRelease].[dbo].[Votes] a INNER JOIN [PressRelease].[dbo].[Questions] b ON a.QID = b.QID 
         WHERE [VoteDate] >= CAST('''+ @dateFrom +''' AS DATETIME2)  AND [VoteDate] <= CAST('''+ @dateTo +'''AS DATETIME2)
    ) t
    PIVOT
    (
        COUNT([Answer])
        FOR [QID] in (' + @columns + ')
    ) p
'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
END
```

Here's the result of this stored proc

[image: Result of the stored proc]

I've been trying different approach but all I get is error to get what I want. I would like to multiply all the numbers in these columns to a number from a column in my other table. The column is NumberOfShares. For every voter, they have their number of shares that would be needed to multiply to their votes. I hope you could help me with this.

[image]

Comment: You should really fix that injection issue. Don't inject `@dFrom`, parametrise it. Rather than images, supply us with sample data (**not** your current results) that in in a consumable format; that means either tabular formatted text or DDL and DML statements.

Comment: @Larnu please see my edited post.

Comment: I don't see any sample data formatted as tubular formatted `text` or DDL and DML statements here?

Answer (score 0):

First let's fix your query first. This part:

```
SET @sql = '
SELECT ' + @columns + '
FROM (
     SELECT b.[QID], a.[Answer]
     FROM [PressRelease].[dbo].[Votes] a
     INNER JOIN [PressRelease].[dbo].[Questions] b ON a.QID = b.QID 
     WHERE a.[VoteDate] >= @dFrom AND a.[VoteDate] <= @dTo
) t
PIVOT(COUNT([Answer]) FOR [QID] in (' + @columns + ')) p
'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@dFrom datetime, @dTo datetime', @dFrom = @dFrom, @dTo = @dTo;
```

So what do you want to multiply by what?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to give the structure of that secret table you want to join and multiply but let's assume this is a "Voters" table:

```
SET @sql = '
SELECT [Answer], ' + @columns + '
FROM (
     SELECT a.[Answer], b.[QID], v.[NumberOfShares]
     FROM [PressRelease].[dbo].[Votes] a
     INNER JOIN [PressRelease].[dbo].[Questions] b ON a.QID = b.QID 
     INNER JOIN [PressRelease].[dbo].[Voters] v    ON a.VoterID = v.VoterID
     WHERE a.[VoteDate] >= @dFrom AND a.[VoteDate] <= @dTo
) t
PIVOT(SUM([NumberOfShares]) FOR [QID] in (' + @columns + ')) p
'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@dFrom datetime, @dTo datetime', @dFrom = @dFrom, @dTo = @dTo;
```